# C# decimal remembers precision: how to adjust

Tags: c#, decimal, precision, digits

Decimal remembers its number of decimal places:

```
Console.WriteLine(1.1m); // 1.1
Console.WriteLine(1.10m); // 1.10
```

I am in a situation where I do not control the serialization (so I cannot use a more explicitly formatted stringify), but there is a requirement to output exactly 2 decimal places.

So, I am trying to force any decimal into the same value *but with 2 decimal places*.

```
var d = Decimal.Round(1.1m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Try to increase precision
Console.WriteLine(d); // Is 1.1, but I need 1.10
```

It is achievable with `ToString("F")` and then `Decimal.Parse()`. But is there a neater way than via `ToString()`?

Comment: If you want to increase "precision" add `0.00m`: `1.1m + 0.00m == 1.10m`

Comment: How are you serializing? You can probably control how decimals are serialized in the serializer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ensure/increase "precision" up to `2` digits after the decimal point you can add `0.00m`:

```
1.1m + 0.00m == 1.10m
```

The same idea generalized:

```
private static decimal FormatOut(decimal value, int afterDecimal) {
  // rounding up and adding 0.00…0 - afterDecimal zeroes        
  return Decimal.Round(value, afterDecimal, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + 
         new decimal(0, 0, 0, false, (byte)afterDecimal);
}

...

decimal result = FormatOut(1.1m, 2);

// 1.10
Console.Write(result);
```